# "bundle exec thin start -C config/thin.yml" does not start thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, thin

in attempt to deploy rails app to server I faced problem that 'thin' does't stars when I try do star it with cap production deploy:start. What is realy strange, than it hasn't any errors.
After this I try do it on deplyment server

```
env RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec thin start -C config/thin.yml

Starting server on /home/deployer/app/current/tmp/sockets/thin.0.sock ... 
Starting server on /home/deployer/app/current/tmp/sockets/thin.1.sock ... 

ls /home/deployer/app/current/tmp/sockets/

ps -aux | grep thin
root     16769  0.0  0.1  15468   908 pts/0    S    11:34   0:00 grep --color=auto thin
```

thin.yml

```
chdir: /home/deployer/app/current
environment: production
timeout: 30
log: /home/deployer/app/current/log/thin.log
pid: /home/deployer/app/current/tmp/pids/thin.pid
socket: /home/deployer/app/current/tmp/sockets/thin.sock
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 10
require: []
wait: 30
servers: 2
daemonize: true
```

What is gone wrong?

In production.log only migrations

```
bundle exec thin start -C config/thin.yml &
```

returns

```
Starting server on /home/deployer/app/current/tmp/sockets/thin.0.sock ... 
Starting server on /home/deployer/app/current/tmp/sockets/thin.1.sock ... 
'bundle exec thin start -C confi…' has ended
```

**Answer**
Okey, answer was log/thin.0.log there are some errors in code

Comment: can you show the content of production.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `demonize` thin for running it in `production` by adding `&`. Try this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec thin start -C config/thin.yml &
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please add `&` at the end of the command.

Comment: After is: `Starting server on /home/deployer/app/current/tmp/sockets/thin.0.sock ... 
Starting server on /home/deployer/app/current/tmp/sockets/thin.1.sock ... 
'bundle exec thin start -C confi…' has ended`